# When does the Nested Interval Property hold for Open Intervals?

Tags: real-analysis

I am aware that the Nested Interval Property (NIP) does not hold for open intervals. The standard way to convince someone of this fact is by providing the standard counterexample  $ \bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty}(0,\frac{1}{n}) $.

What I'm wresting with is whether NIP ever holds for open intervals. It turns out that, if in  $I_n=(a_n,b_n)$, $(a_n)$ is a strictly increasing sequence and $(b_n)$ is a strictly decreasing one, then NIP holds!

My reference for the above observation: [Nested intervals theorem - a special case on open intervals](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3716576/736894) .

**Question:** Are there any cases other cases where the NIP holds for open intervals?

Comment: Yes.  Another case is when the length $b_n-a_n$ does not converge to $0$.

Comment: Consider the nested intervals $(-\frac1n , \frac1n)$ which all contain $0$ so the intersection must be non-empty.